# Linux Mint: Keybinging Alt+^

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I wanted to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> for open Quake but it seems Linux Mint is already using it for switching between open programs (similar <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>). I tried to deactive this keybing in the keyboard settings but could not find this specific keybinding.

How can I change the setting so that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> is available?

Comment: In the title, you mentioned that you need `Alt+^` shortcut (by the way, does that actually mean `Alt+Shift+6`?), but in the question you wrote that you need `Ctrl+Alt` instead. What do you really need? On my Linux Mint 13, it's impossible to set plain `Ctrl+Alt` shortcut (need some more key), but `Alt+Shift+6` is easily allowed.

Comment: it should be alt+^. i changed it in my question.

Comment: Well, strangely enough, but I can set the shortcut `Alt+Shift+^` to some internal action (say, I just set it for maximizing window and it works), but if I set it for running some application, it doesn't work. No idea now.